# How to calculate a subjects percentage in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My problem is about calculating a subjects percentage. I have the EnterMark model. Which contains the section_id. Using that I can get the number of students in a particular section. But the problem comes about when calculating the percentage for each subject (In chart view).

Controller

```
@mark_percent = EnterMark.where(:school_id => params[:school], :course_id =>  params[:course], :section_id => params[:view])
```

View

```
<% @mark_percent.each do |i| %>     
  <% @count = i.students.count %> 
    ['<%= i.subject.subject %>', <%= (i.subject_mark_total) / @count  %>],
<% end %>
```

But @count not taken for each subject. Please help.

Comment: I don't know about your issue, but in general, avoid adding local variables in your views.

Comment: `i.subject_total_mark/100`...I am not getting you model but you can use this simple math for calculating percentage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

`per = "#{(i.subject_mark_total.to_f / @count) * 100}%"`

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to find an average for each course, is that right?  Like [Pierre-Louis Gottfrois](https://stackoverflow.com/users/788770/pierre-louis-gottfrois) said, you should try to not define variables inside the view.

In the Course.rb model you could make something like this:

```
def avg
  total = self.subject_mark_total.to_f
  students = self.students.count
  # get average of scores and round to two decimal places
  average = total / students
  average.round(2)
end
```

and in the view call `<%= course.avg %>`

Apologies if i've misunderstood what you're asking for!